# Gremlin math step has issues if a reserved word "exp" is used in a label name

Tags: math, gremlin, reserved

I have a query which has the math function like below,

```
math('number1-expected_value').next()
```

It throws error as

```
**GremlinServerError: 499: {"detailedMessage":"Unknown function or variable 'cted_value' at pos 20 in expression 'number1 - expected_value'","requestId":"01e3f9e6-3cf2-4af0-bf94-5a4979d488b4","code":"InvalidParameterException"}**
```

I know, the exp keyword is reserved for exponentiation operation. Is there anyone who knows how to use a keyword as a normal string inside the math function in gremlin?

Note:
when I change the variable as "eexpected_value", it works. If I choose expeected_value, it throws same error. Hence expe and expee make operation of exponen

Comment: This looks like an issue with the EXP4J parser that Gremlin uses for the `math` step. Are you able to open a Jira issue for this in the TinkerPop repo?

Comment: Added a comment to the answer that this is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue in the Gremlin `math` step which is built using EXP4J. I have opened the following Jira issue to track within the Apache TinkerPop project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2856

For now, the best workaround as you discovered is just to avoid using variable names that contain any of the `math` built in function names (like `exp`).

**UPDATED 2023-05-11**

As of Apache TinkerPop release 3.6.3 this issue is now fixed.